# PermitAll not working in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have two rules, the first one every url from oauth/** should be without security and and other url have to security. But now all urls are secure include url from oauth/**.
This is my security config rule.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // JWT dont need CSRF
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("oauth/**").permitAll().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }

}
```

when I request the url http://localhost:8080/oauth/fb that is enter my JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, and I want this url don't enter this filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can override configure method with WebSecurity parameter.

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception
{
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("oauth/**");
}
```

This method should be used when serving static content such as css/* js/*, suggested in the documentation, however I couldn't find another way to permit URL mapping with custom filter in Spring Security.

Comment: This is sad. It should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:http pattern="/support/**" security="none"/>
```

You would probably need to write the Java equivalent of the above XML configuration. Basically, you are setting a new filter chain with no security for the above pattern.

Comment: I am using spring boot, I dont using XML to config.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. My security config:

```
// ... imports
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                          PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                          JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtFilter = new JwtFilter(jwtProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

And my security filter:

```
// ... imports
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final int TOKEN_START_POSITION = 7;

    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    public JwtFilter(JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
        this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = getTokenFromRequest((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        if (token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Map<String, Object> properties = jwtProvider.getUserPropertiesFromToken(token);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    properties.get("login"),
                    null,
                    (Set<GrantedAuthority>) properties.get("authirities"));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private String getTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearer = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
        if (bearer != null && bearer.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            return bearer.substring(TOKEN_START_POSITION);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The reason my code didn't work for me was that I skipped the line `filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);` in my filter, i.e. I didn't pass on the request and response to the next entity in the chain.